# PyQt WebCam Image on Thread

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt4

I am trying to get live webcam view using PyQt using following code

```
class LoadImageThread(QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self):
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

  def __del__(self):
    self.wait()

  def run(self):
    c = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        return_val, img = c.read()
        w, h =320, 240
        data = img.tostring(("raw", "BGRX"))
        qimage = QtGui.QImage(img, w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
        qpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(w,h)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
        #ui.label.setPixmap(pix)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('showImage(QPixmap, int, int)'), pix, 320, 240)

#########################################
def showImage(p, w, h):
   ui.label.setPixmap(p)

ui.connect(thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("showImage(QPixmap, int, int)"), showImage)
```

But i got following error

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

Any Solution ?. Thanks

Comment: As the error says, using pixmaps in a non-GUI is not safe. However, it's safe to use `QImage`, so emit that instead, and then create the pixmap in `showImage`.

Comment: @berak. Do not use comments, if you don't know how to help.

Comment: @ekhumoro, - touche !.